# creating new dataframe with manhattan distance in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to create a dataframe containing the manhattan distance between two dataframes with the same columns, and I need the indexes of each dataframe to be the index and column name, so for example lets say I have these two dataframes:

```
x_train :
index a b c
11    2 5 7
23    4 2 0
312   2 2 2
x_test : 
index a b c
22    1 1 1
30    2 0 0
```

so the columns match but the size and indexes do not, the expected dataframe would look like this:

```
dist_dataframe:
index 11 23 312
22    11 5  3
30    12 4  4
```

and what I have right now is this:

```
def manhattan_distance(a, b):
    return sum(abs(e1-e2) for e1, e2 in zip(a,b))

def calc_distance(X_test,X_train):
    dist_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(index=X_test.index,columns = X_train.index)
    for i in X_train.index:
        for j in X_test.index:
            dist_dataframe.loc[i,j]=manhattan_distance(X_train.loc[[i]],X_test.loc[[j]])
    return dist_dataframe
```

what I get from the code I have is this dataframe:

```
dist_dataframe:
index
index 11  23  312
22    NaN NaN NaN
30    NaN NaN NaN
```

I get the right dataframe size except that it has 2 rows called indexes that I get from the creation of the new dataframe, and also I get an error no matter what I do in the manhattan calculation line, can anyone help me out here please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem in your code

There is a very small problem in your code, i.e. accessing values in `dist_dataframe`. So,instead of `dist_dataframe.loc[i,j]`, you should reverse the order of i and j and make it like `dist_dataframe.loc[j,i]`

### More efficient solution

It will work fine but since you are a new contributor, I would also like to point out the efficiency of your code. Always try to replace loops with pandas in-built functions. Since they are written in C, it makes them much faster. So here is a more efficient solution:

```
def manhattan_distance(a, b):
    return sum(abs(e1-e2) for e1, e2 in zip(a,b))

def xtrain_distance(row):
    distances = {}
    for i,each in x_train.iterrows():
        distances[i] = manhattan_distance(each,row)
    return distances

result = x_test.apply(xtrain_distance, axis=1)

# converting into dataframe
pd.DataFrame(dict(result)).transpose()
```

It also produces same output and on your example and you can't see any time difference. But when run on a larger size (same data scaled over 20 times), i.e. 60 `x_train` samples and 40 `x_test` samples, here is the time difference:

Your solution took: `929 ms`

This solution took: `207 ms`

It got 4x faster just by eliminating one for loop. Note that, it can be made more efficient but for the sake of demonstration, I have used this solution.

Comment: Thank you, it worked.
I upvoted but it doesn't show it :/.
Also thanks for the tip on the efficient solution! but I am not sure I can use it for my assignment as we were not allowed to use any function, which performs any of the vector distance functions, not sure if your solution uses any tho, would be glad to know

Comment: Hi @bendush, the solution doesn't use any function involving vectorization. It only uses apply method in pandas which is, in simpler terms, efficiently iterating over dataframe along any axis, processing the function on each item and hence giving the output dataframe. To have a better understanding and comparson with vectorization methods, refer this: https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6

Comment: thanks! I didn't understand what is the variable row that you get in xtrain_distance, if you can please explain it I would appreciate it!

Comment: Sure. When you use apply attribute in pandas, it takes function name as an argument. And then it passes every row  (if axis=1) or column (if axis = 0) of the dataframe to that function as the input. In our case, all rows of the dataframe x_test is passed one by one to the function and the output is a pandas series of function responses.